# Not able to select links from a module on a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have build a scraper to extract links from a company's website (I have permission), however when I try to add in the url where the jobs are posted, I'm only able to retrieve some of the links. It seems that the job's are stored in some kind of module whereby I can't access them using my scraper.

html parbase section is the html name of the module I can't seem to access

**Question**

*Why is the scraper not able to pull the urls for the job posts from the link I have provided below?*

**LINK TO JOS POSTINGS HERE: https://www.pwc.dk/da/karriere/ledige-stillinger.html**

**Code for scraper**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url = "http://www.pwc.dk/da/karriere/ledige-stillinger.html"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
            print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)
```

Comment: Looks like the items are being loaded by JS, search how to use `selenium` for that task.

Comment: Perfect - thanks Vinicius!

Answer (score 1):

As the webpage is a javascript-heavy one, you need to use selenium to gatecrash. Install selenium and give this a try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.pwc.dk/da/karriere/ledige-stillinger.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()
for item in soup.select(".vbtitle a"):
    print(item.get("href"))
```